# Преобразовать число с запятой в число с точкой

Tags: linux, bash

Из top получаю необходимое значение загрузки ЦП процессом, оно выдается в виде 10,0 (может быть и 1,6 к примеру) и может быть больше или меньше. Необходимо сравнить это значение с пороговым (статическим) и в случае превышения порогового выполнить действие.

Через bc что-то не выходит, но через него можно успешно сравнивать числа вида 10.0. Так что подойдет вариант замены "," на ".". Как это сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

программа *top* нормально локализована, и поэтому для правильного отображения т.н. «десятичной точки» (*decimal point*) использует текущую локаль.

у вас, скорее всего, используется локаль `ru_RU.UTF-8`.

посмотреть значение «десятичной точки» для какой-нибудь локали можно так:

```
$ LC_ALL=имя-локали locale -c decimal_point
```

например, для `ru_RU.UTF-8` это будет запятая:

```
$ LC_ALL=ru_RU.UTF-8 locale -c decimal_point
LC_NUMERIC
,
```

а для специальной локали `C` (она же [«умолчальная» «posix-овая» локаль](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/87745/110559)) — точка:

```
$ LC_ALL=C locale -c decimal_point
LC_NUMERIC
.
```

---

### резюме:

если вы будете запускать программу *top* с локалью `C`, т.е., не просто:

```
$ top опции-и-параметры
```

а

```
$ LC_ALL=C top опции-и-параметры
```

вы получите в выводе то, что вам требуется — точку в качестве разделителя целой и дробной части:

```
$ LC_ALL=C top -bn1 -p1 | tail -n 1
    1 root      20   0  2300  744  640 S   0.0  0.0   0:27.46 init
```

Comment: Имеет смысл так делать всегда, когда парсите вывод какой-нибудь команды, некоторые команды в других локалях могут неожиданно выдавать данные совсем по-другому.

Comment: Спасибо, решение понравилось, сделал именно так.

Answer (score 2):

Bash умеет это сам:

```
$ a="10,32"
$ echo ${a/,/.}
10.32
```

Comment: а чтобы заменить все вхождения `,`, надо ещё один слэш добавить: `${a//,/.}`

Answer (score 1):

Полагаю, можно попробовать с помощью `sed 's/foo/bar/'` - заменит foo на bar, в Вашем случае записать `sed 's/,/./'`

Comment: sed умеет читать переменные? Не хочется плодить файлы/логи

Comment: Как пример `HER="10,0"; echo $HER |sed 's/,/./'`

Comment: Спасибо, с HER'ом пошло как надо ^^